# Wireless connection intermittent on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have a Rosewill RNX-n300 PCI wireless card, and since installing 12.04 the connection intermittently stops receiving data. The problem seems to be worse when downloading files, whether from the web, Update Manager, or from the Software Center.

The network manager never shows loss of connection, and disconnecting then reconnecting wireless solves the issue. Disabling `-n` speed in terminal improved performance a bit.

I have also disabled power management for the device with (I think) `iwconfig`, in addition to disabling the `-n` speed setting. I have also tried disabling IPV6.

Answer (score 2):

So the Rosewill has an RT2760 chipset. After doing some research, I went to synaptic and installed the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.3-precise-generic package
```

and then rebooting.

Many thanks for this solution go to user *Chili555* at the Ubuntu forums. I am re-posting here in hope that it helps somebody else.